# need to reset a particular field's value using antd form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to  reset a field value on the onchange of another field value using antd form. It is based on index.

```
this.form.resetFields({[`CorName_${index}`]:''})
```

I tried this, But error occurs. Is there any other way to clear particular index's field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

antd form resetFields only takes array of fields as parameter.
Try below code:

```
form.resetFields([`CorName_${index}`]);
```